# Consuming Restful service on Android - intent not started?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am implementing the consumption of a RESTful service on Android (my first Android experience), as proposed on GoogleIO (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE). I try to implement a GET request and I think I implemented everything as proposed, but it seems not to be working.

Here are my [ServiceHelper](http://pastebin.com/hW5nBVrX#) and [Service](http://pastebin.com/n7Dpj8kc) classes:

After debugging I know that it gets to getPersons() method in the ServiceHelper class:

```
public void getPersons ( Context context, ResultReceiver receiver ) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent ( Intent.ACTION_SYNC, null, context,   PersonService.class );
    intent.putExtra ( PersonService.EXTRA_STATUS, receiver );
    intent.putExtra ( PersonService.EXTRA_REST_OPERATION, PersonService.GENERAL_REST_OPERATION );
    context.startService ( intent );
}
```

However, it never gets to onCreate(), onHandleIntent() or getPersons() in the Service class:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent ( Intent intent ) {
Log.d ( TAG, "onHandleIntent()" );

final String restOperation = intent.getStringExtra ( EXTRA_REST_OPERATION );
    if ( GENERAL_REST_OPERATION.equals ( restOperation ) )
    getPersons ( intent );
}
```

Do you have a clue what goes wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you have the service added in `AndroidManifest.xml`? Something like `<service android:name=".service.PersonService" />`

Comment: That's right, I have forgotten that! I added the line that you suggested and it's working now. Thank you very much